# Get the class of nullable type

Tags: reflection, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I am trying to match the type of the nullable `String?` in a Kotlin reflection exercise:

```
data class Test(a: String, b: String?)
val test = Test("1", "2")
val properties = test::class.declaredMemberProperties
val propertyNames = properties.joinToString(",") { 
        when (it.returnType) {
            String?::class.createType() -> "string?"
            String::class.createType() -> "string"
            else -> throw Exception()
        }
}
```

Alas, it is failing with the error, `Type in a class literal must not be nullable`, for `String?::class`.

Comment: A `String?` isn't a class of its own and doesn't have a class object. `String?::class` could be the class object of `String` or the class object of `null` (which doesn't make sense). This would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `createType` function has an optional nullable parameter that seemed to work when I tested it.

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.full.*

String::class.createType(nullable = true) -> "string?"
```

Comment: Alas, this answer is only valid for the jvm target.